# Highstock stacked bar chart with slider overlayed on the graph

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to implement a bar chart with slider overlayed on the graph similar to following image [Bar chart with slider overlayed on chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LigWd.png).

Is there any existing highstocks api options that I can take leverage of to implement this behaviour?

Note: I tried with navigator option available with high stock. But Navigator option helps to display a slider below the graph. I want to silder to be overlayed on the chart itself

Comment: JsFiddle for implementation with navigator option : https://jsfiddle.net/srikriss/L1o2hzsw/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the main chart and just display the navigator:  https://jsfiddle.net/bqhz2fwn/

The only changes I made to your fiddle were to hide the xAxis and make the height of the yAxis 0:

```
    "xAxis": {
  "categories": [
    1996,
    1997,
    1998,
    1999,
    2000,
    2001,
    2002,
    2003,
    2004,
    2005,
    2006,
    2007,
    2008,
    2009,
    2010,
    2011,
    2012,
    2013,
    2014,
    2015,
    2016
  ],
  lineWidth: 0,
  tickLength: 0,
  labels: {
    enabled: false
  }
},
yAxis: {
  height: 0,
  gridLineWidth: 0,
  labels: {
    enabled: false
  }
},
```

And then increase the height of the navigator to fill the space:

```
    "navigator": {
  height: 275,
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Hiding the main chart and displaying only navigator affects the chart's readability (1st and last column not visible completely). Is there a way to change it?

Answer (score 0):

1. From the API options you can achieve it by manipulating navigator options such as: **height**, **margin** etc. However, this solution, in my opinion, disturbs the chart working and readability.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nqeuhdgk/

```
"navigator": {
    maskInside: false,
  yAxis: {
    lineWidth: 1,
    minorTicks: true,
    labels: {
      enabled: true
    }
  },
  height: 260,
  margin: 150,
  "enabled": true,
  "series": {
    "stacking": 'normal',
    "type": 'column',
    dataGrouping: {
        enabled: false
    }
  },

},
```

Notice that comparing to your demo, not every column is shown and the yAxis readability is different.

---

2. I did some changes in the core code and here is my output, which is a better solution I think.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/07mdwou6/

Test it and let me know what do you think.

---

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/navigator.height

Comment: Thanks. I do agree showing only navigator affects the readability of the chart. Your second solution looks good. 

One small question is it possible to prevent main chart from updating on dragging the handle in the navigator ?